# How can I apply a rule to update records in a field based on a condition and by grouping the data

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, window-functions

I am trying to do this task in sql. but I am not able to derive a logic that helps getting me this output.

[image: i am trying to do this task in sql. but i am not able to derive a logic that helps getting me this output.need help.]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 1):

It *looks like* you want to bring the name of the player whose code is "x" for each id. If so, one option uses window functions:

```
select id, playercode, playername,
    max(case when playercode = 'x' then playername end) over(partition by id) requiredoutput
from mytable
```

If your database does not support window functions, one option uses a correlated subquery. Assuming no duplicates on `(id, playercode)`:

```
select id, playercode, playername,
    (
        select t1.playername 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.id = t.id and t1.playercode = 'x'
    ) requiredoutput
from mytable t
```

Comment: Thankyou. one small doubt. what if i have some other player codes like 'Z' for which i do not want to update or assign the value of 'X' ? i want to keep those records as the way they are!

Comment: @sam: you would typically use a `case` expression, like `case when playercode = 'z' then playername else  max(case when playercode = 'x' then playername end) over(partition by id) end`

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an update statement maybe something like this would work

```
with upd_cte as (
    select distinct id, player_name
    from tTable
    where Playercode='x')
update t
set requiredoutput=u.player_name
from tTable t
     join upd_cte u on t.id=u.id;
```